# How to compare two maps by their values and print max value for each key(key is common in both map)

Tags: java, collections

```
void displayFeedback(){
    Map<String, Integer> maths = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    maths.put("Nirmala", 70);
    maths.put("Subaksha", 80);
    Map<String, Integer> english = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    english.put("Nirmala", 75);
    english.put("Subaksha", 60);
    //same staffs taking two different subjects maths and english 
    //values taken as feedback for each subject
    // i need to compare both subject feedback and print only max as o/p
    System.out.println(maths);
    System.out.println(maths.entrySet());
    //maths.
    //maths.entrySet();
    //Collections.max(coll, comp)
    Map<String, Integer> top = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    System.out.println(maths.size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> math: maths.entrySet()){
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> eng: english.entrySet()){   
        //for(int i = 0;i<maths.size();i++){
            //math.comparingByValue()
            System.out.println(math.getValue()+" "+eng.getValue());
            //Collections.max(math.getValue(), eng.getValue());
        if(math.getValue() <= eng.getValue()){
            //System.out.println(" math <= eng");

        }else
        {
            //System.out.println("math > eng");
        }
```

Teachers are common in both map ,they are handling both maths and eng subject
and their feed back in each subjeck getting as values for both subjects

I need to compare and find maximum feedback value and print only max value to
each teacher....t
teacher is common key in both map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the value of english feedback map using the math entrySet() iterator key and select the max value

```
        Map<String, Integer> maths = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        maths.put("Nirmala", 70);
        maths.put("Subaksha", 80);
        Map<String, Integer> english = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        english.put("Nirmala", 75);
        english.put("Subaksha", 60);

        System.out.println(english.entrySet());
        System.out.println(maths.entrySet());

        Map<String, Integer> top = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> math: maths.entrySet()){    
            System.out.println( "Teacher : " +math.getKey() + " Max Feedback :" + Math.max(math.getValue(), english.get(math.getKey())));
          }
```

Comment: Hi Deep, it is working fine. as a beginner i am not aware of that Deep . thanks for for your time. math kind of function comes under which topic Deep let me start studying those functions. thanks much for your time ..!!

Comment: @user2926683 Glad that i could help. Math class comes under java.lang.math and it provides basic numeric operations.

Comment: Superb bro...!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine suggstion ;)

```
private void printMaxValues(Map<String, Integer> first, Map<String, Integer> second) {
    Set<String> keys = first.keySet();
    for (String s : keys) {
        Integer val1 = first.get(s);
        Integer val2 = second.get(s);
        if (val1 == null && val2 == null) {
            System.out.println("No values for key: " + s);
        } else if (val1 == null) {
            System.out.println(s + "=" + val2);
        } else if (val2 == null) {
            System.out.println(s + "=" + val1);
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + "=" + Math.max(val1, val2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sergiy thanks your time, this logic also working fine thanks for your support and letting me to learn new logics.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow :

**1.** build a `map` from the subjects as *key is the teacher*, and *value is all its feebacks*

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> feedbacks = 
                           Stream.of(maths, english)
                                 .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), 
                                              e -> new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(e.getValue())), 
                                             (l1, l2)-> {l1.addAll(l2); return l1;}));

System.out.println(feedbacks); //{Subaksha=[80, 60], Nirmala=[70, 75]}
```

---

**2.** buid a `map` from the feedbacks as *key is the teacher*, and *value is the max of its feedback*

```
Map<String, Integer> maxs = feedbacks.entrySet().stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey(),
                                         e-> e.getValue().stream().max(Integer::compare).get()));

System.out.println(maxs);     //{Nirmala=75, Subaksha=80}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
static <V extends Comparable<V>>
boolean valuesEquals(Map<?,V> map1, Map<?,V> map2) {
    List<V> values1 = new ArrayList<V>(map1.values());
    List<V> values2 = new ArrayList<V>(map2.values());
    Collections.sort(values1);
    Collections.sort(values2);
    return values1.equals(values2);
}
```

or

```
map1.keySet().equals(map2.keySet())
```

to compare values. And if equals is true then you find greater Key of the two values.

Refer : http://thelogofthewook.blogspot.com/2011/12/hashmap-comparison-how-to-compare-two.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper Collection for each Teacher key (`Map<String, Collection<Integer>>`) that you fill up by iterating over both existing maps and then putting the scores into them.

Or you could create a Java 8 Stream over both map's entrySets and then merge them into one Map by calling the Collectors utils:

```
Map<String, Optional<Integer>> data = Arrays.asList( map1.entrySet(), map2.entrySet() )
            .stream()
            .flatMap( Set::stream )
            .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Entry::getKey, HashMap::new, Collectors.mapping( Entry::getValue, Collectors.maxBy( Integer::compare ) ) ) );

    for( Entry<String, Optional<Integer>> entry : data.entrySet() )
    {
        System.out.println( entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().orElse( 0 ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you will get feedback for every teacher in every subject, you can use following.

```
Map<String, Integer> maths = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
maths.put("T1", 75);
maths.put("T2", 68);
maths.put("T3", 80);

Map<String, Integer> english = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
english.put("T1",60);
english.put("T2",70);
english.put("T3",79);

for(String s:maths.keySet())
    System.out.println("Teacher "+s+" with max feedback:"+Math.max(maths.get(s),english.get(s)));
```

Comment: this one also work fine Pramod, all i comes to from you senior people is Math function...

Comment: @user2926683 happy to help!